# Holding wifi locks in a foreground service

Tags: android, service, foreground, wifimanager

I'm writing an Android app that uses a couple of *NIX binaries which have been cross-compiled to ARM that provide network based services on the Android device (roughly ~400,000 lines of C code which is why i chose to cross-compile rather than re-write it in java).

The binaries run as Android/linux daemons (the app forks them via SU using Runtime.getRuntime().exec()).  So that they can continue to provide service when the device goes to sleep, I offer the user the option of a wakelock - acquiring WifiManager.WifiLock in a foreground service (foreground to reduce the chance of the service being killed by process management and losing the locks).

This seems to work ok but i'm wondering if there are better / alternate ways of holding the locks or keeping wifi up than using locking in a foreground service? Thanks.